# Get google sheet info and send it via JSON to a backend

Tags: javascript, python, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to make a script that takes data from a row in Google Sheets example:

```
Id     Name       Amount
1      Jesus      200             SEND SCRIPT
```

In that google sheet documentIi want to create a script for very row that will take that data and send it to a back end for complete an specific function.

Example when user clicks SEND SCRIPT

It will make an ajax request with a JSON format to a back end sending the data of the row (id, name, amount).

I don't know how to start here, I would like to hear your suggestions.

Comment: The question is too broad and it's not clear which language you will use (JavaScript/Google Apps Script), Python, both?

Comment: @Rubén ok i will only need how to get all the values of a row using Google Apps Script. If i click an image in row 1 for example. How can i get the data of that specific row (where image that runs the script is located).

Comment: @Rubén so every row, will have that image and the function get data of that row where the image(button) is located

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add to it all the relevant details including a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested on [ask].